# strongswan vpn with windows 10 client - does not connect

Tags: vpn, strongswan

I am trying to run an strongswan VPN server to use with windows-10 clients using their builtin VPN feature (to make it easy for the client users)

Whenever trying to connect, windows shows that the user/pass is accepted, then 'connecting, and then fails. The server log shows an error, "deleting half open IDE_SA ... after timeout" .

output from "sudo systemctl status strongswan.service", with last 10 lines of log:

```
 strongswan.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/strongswan.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-12-04 13:15:05 GMT; 1min 38s ago
 Main PID: 1859 (starter)
    Tasks: 18 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan.service
           ââ1859 /usr/lib/ipsec/starter --daemon charon --nofork
           ââ1873 /usr/lib/ipsec/charon

Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[IKE] authentication of 'CN=vpn.example.com' (myself) with RSA signature successful
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[IKE] sending end entity cert "CN=vpn.example.com"
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[ENC] splitting IKE message (1948 bytes) into 2 fragments
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/2) ]
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/2) ]
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.2.9[4500] to 109.41.64.240[6977] (1248 bytes)
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi ipsec[1859]: 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.2.9[4500] to 109.41.64.240[6977] (768 bytes)
Dec 04 13:15:34 raspberrypi charon[1873]: 14[IKE] sending keep alive to 109.41.64.240[6977]
Dec 04 13:15:43 raspberrypi charon[1873]: 15[JOB] deleting half open IKE_SA with 109.41.64.240 after timeout
```

Fiddling forth-and back from some posts about strongswan and windows, I cannot find a fault. Reworked this question now as it seems that systemctl restart did not parse the config again? I kept getting the same output all over whatever I changed. Doing a stop and start seems to help.

(currently trying this within the local network, therefore all IPs are in 192.168.* . the VPN range is supposed to be 172.17.0.0/16

/etc/ipsec.conf is this:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file


config setup
    strictcrlpolicy=no
    uniqueids=never

# Add connections here.

# Sample VPN connections

conn %default
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes256-sha1!
    dpdaction=clear
    rekey=no
    dpddelay=300s
    fragmentation=yes

conn win7
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    left=%any
#    leftid=192.168.2.9
    leftcert=server.cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftsendcert=always
    right=%any
    rightip=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=172.17.0.128/25
    rightdns=192.168.2.1
    rightsendcert=never
#    eap_identity=%identity
    eap_identity=%any
    auto=add


include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc
```

In windows 10 (home), I choose connection name 'test', server address 192.168.2.9, VPN type "automatic", type of sign-in "User name and password".

file /etc/ipsec.secrets has a user named 'user':
# This file holds shared secrets or RSA private keys for authentication.

```
# RSA private key for this host, authenticating it to any other host
# which knows the public part.

# this file is managed with debconf and will contain the automatically created private key
#include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.secrets.inc

: RSA "server.key.pem"
user : EAP "testpassword_preliminary"
```

I generated the certs on the server with these commandlines:

```
ipsec pki --gen --size 4096 --type rsa --outform pem > ca.key.pem
ipsec pki --self --in ca.key.pem --type rsa --dn "CN=VPN Server CA" --ca --lifetime 3650 --outform pem > ca.cert.pem
ipsec pki --gen --size 4096 --type rsa --outform pem > server.key.pem
ipsec pki --pub --in server.key.pem --type rsa | ipsec pki --issue --lifetime 2750 --cacert ca.cert.pem --cakey ca.key.pem --dn "CN=vpn.example.com" --san="vpn.example.com" --flag serverAuth --flag ikeIntermediate --outform pem > server.cert.pem
```

Comment: That log does not match your config. Please post the current log.

Comment: Hi @ecdsa , thanks for your comment. I tried it again today and I got a completely different output. Is it possible that  systemctl restart strongswan   does not reload theconfig? I kept getting the same output all over. And now the EAP method-fail result. Updates the outputs.

Comment: No, it should reload the config. You are now missing the necessary EAP plugins. If you do this on Debian/Ubuntu, try installing the _libcharon-extra-plugins_ and _libcharon-extauth-plugins_ packages.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did not see that the error meant that the module does not load. Now it is installed and the connection gets one step further. To now hang after connecting. I found a hint that moving 'fragmentation=yes' to the defaults part would help. It didn't.

Comment: Where the setting is configured doesn't matter and fragmentation is enabled by default anyway with newer releases. Could be that fragments are too big, or, perhaps more likely, that the client doesn't like/trust the server certificate. The hostname/IP you configure on the client must be contained in the certificate as SAN, plus the CA certificate must be installed in the correct credential store on the client.